# I am having Issues with data types not appearing in the data architect and would like to know what could be causing this

Tags: advantage-database-server

The datatype char does not appear in the Data Architect for version 10. It now shows up as character.

I cannot find anything in the documentation for this type.

I have spent months developing a WCF Custom Adapter for the Advantage Database. Now I am getting data type exceptions because of the CHARACTER data type.

Does anyone know of any other undocumented modifcations to the MetaData?

Answer (score 2):

CHAR and Character are the same thing.  I believe the difference you are seeing in ARC 10 vs earlier versions of ARC (I am assuming here, sorry) was a cosmetic bug fix.  In ARC 9.1 for example, if you click the drop down it was listed as Character.

Using sp_getColumns stored procedure I see that the type is returned the same for both ADS 10.0 and ADS 9.1 (both are CHAR).

What sort of errors are you getting as far as data type exceptions?

Comment: This didn't happen in version 9. I am using sp_getProcedureColumns

Comment: This still does not give much information, but with some more assuming I think I understand the change.
in 9.x the TYPE_NAME appears to return CHAR and in 10 it now seems to return CHARACTER.
So a couple of things here. A) sp_getProcedureColumns is undocumented and as a result subject to change since there is not documentation (in my opinion)
B)DATA_TYPE returns the same for both (1).  Maybe use this as a workaround
C)Perhaps you can call support and ask if this change was intentional.  Maybe a bug?

Comment: it is definitely a bug and we will record these and many other issues directly with Sybase.

Comment: IMO the documentation is useless